# How can I fix if: Invalid search bound (wrong side of point) in mu4e?

Tags: mu4e

mu4e works quite well here, but I have one big problem: When I try to reply to an email, I get this error:

```
  re-search-forward("^#![ ]?\\([a-zA-Z_./]+\\)" 50 t)
  (if (re-search-forward "^#![ ]?\\([a-zA-Z_./]+\\)" 50 t) (let ((interpreter (buffer-substring (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))) (if (or (not (= (string-match "/" interpreter) 0)) (not (and (file-exists-p interpreter) (file-executable-p interpreter)))) (message "%sWarning: `%s' is not a valid interpreter."))))
  (save-excursion (goto-char 1) (if (re-search-forward "^#![ ]?\\([a-zA-Z_./]+\\)" 50 t) (let ((interpreter (buffer-substring (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))) (if (or (not (= (string-match "/" interpreter) 0)) (not (and (file-exists-p interpreter) (file-executable-p interpreter)))) (message "%sWarning: `%s' is not a valid interpreter.")))))
  shebang-check-interpreter()
  run-hooks(after-save-hook)
  basic-save-buffer(nil)
  save-buffer()
  (closure (mu4e-compose-mode-abbrev-table mu4e-compose-mode-syntax-table t) nil (if (eq mu4e-compose-type 'reply) (progn (mu4e~remove-refs-maybe))) (if use-hard-newlines (progn (mu4e-send-harden-newlines))) (set-buffer-modified-p t) (save-buffer) (mu4e~compose-setup-fcc-maybe) (widen))()
  run-hooks(message-send-hook)
  message-send(nil)
  message-send-and-exit(nil)
  funcall-interactively(message-send-and-exit nil)
  call-interactively(message-send-and-exit nil nil)
  command-execute(message-send-and-exit)
```

The normal mail headers, when replying, look like this:

```
From: Markus Grunwald <markus@the-grue.de>
To: Markus Grunwald <markus@the-grue.de>
Subject: Re: Attachment Signatur?
Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 14:52:15 +0200
In-reply-to: <87d078qazs.fsf@bob.galaxy.home>
--text follows this line--
```

When I delete the `In-reply-to:` header, the mail is sent...

Answer (score 1):

I installed shebang.el from emacswiki:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MakingScriptsExecutableOnSave

Removing it solved the issue.

Comment: If you have an idea why it solved the issue then it might help to add that info to your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.